# How to join table and display it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried to combine 2 tables.

Example, table A and B.

- Table A have 2 columns (id and value)
- Table A have 3 rows (1, a), (1, b) and (1, c).
- Table B have 1 column and 1 row (id) is (1)

I have tried to do it with **join table**, results: 3 rows id and value is (1, a), (1, b), (1, c)

Its not what i want, i need to create like:

**Results:**

Only 1 row, id is (1) and value is (a, b, c)

**But**, i just want to get "c" data from "value".

**So**, the result that I want is (1, c), and how?

**Edit:**

Check, theres work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0fd3b/2

Its not work on my code, resluts is not found. Check this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['page_no']) && $_GET['page_no']!="") {
  $page_no = $_GET['page_no'];
}
else {
  $page_no = 1;
}
$total_records_per_page = 3;
$offset = ($page_no-1) * $total_records_per_page;
$previous_page = $page_no - 1;
$next_page = $page_no + 1;
$adjacents = "2"; 
$result_count = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) As total_records FROM b");
$total_records = mysqli_fetch_array($result_count);
$total_records = $total_records['total_records'];
  $total_no_of_pages = ceil($total_records / $total_records_per_page);
$second_last = $total_no_of_pages - 1; // total page minus 1
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, a.meta_key, a.meta_value FROM a JOIN b USING (id) WHERE a.meta_value = 'value2' LIMIT $offset, $total_records_per_page");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['key'];
    echo $row['value'];
  }
}
else {
  echo "no found";
}
?>
// pagination
....
```

Comment: Why "c" and not some other row?

Comment: You need to explain the logic for selecting 1,c

Comment: I only want to display "c"  for this page, and all rows for other page. Like for profile page, and detail profile for all rows

Comment: Table A is profile and table B is detail profile

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
select a.*
from a join
     b
     on a.id = b.id
order by a.value desc
limit 1;
```

I'm a bit confused on why a `join` is needed at all:

```
select a.*
from a
order by value desc
limit 1;
```

But you seem to want the `join`.

Comment: Table a and b is connected

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below. I hope it will get the result that you want.

```
SELECT a.id, a.value, 
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id; 
ORDER BY
    a.id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Only 1 row, id is (1) and value is (a, b, c)

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY value) values
FROM a
JOIN b USING (id)
GROUP BY id
```

> But, i just want to get "c" data from "value".

```
SELECT id, a.value
FROM a
JOIN b USING (id)
WHERE a.value = 'c'
```

Comment: I try your code bro, but i get new problem, i update my post can you check?

Comment: @Lingga *but i get new problem* Be more specific - describe this "new problem" detailed, like "the output is ... but I need ... because ...". PS. If the output is correct on the MySQL level, and you have a problem at PHP level - then create new question for to solve this another separate problem (look at the list of the reasons for to close the question - you will see "Needs more focus. This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.").